# Drop All Rows That Aren't The Beginning or End of Week

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a stock data dataframe with dates as the index column. What I'd like to do is drop all rows that aren't the beginning or ending of the week, effectively leaving me with a dataframe of (mostly) Monday's and Friday's. The trick is, I don't want to just look for Monday's and Friday's because some weeks are short weeks, starting on Tuesday's or ending on Thursday's (or otherwise. Maybe some weeks have a Wednesday off too?).

[image: Dataset]

The logic I have right now (and a reproducible code) for dropping all rows that aren't the beginning of the week looks like this:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("once")
from datetime import datetime, timedelta





# Import a stock dataset from Yahoo
ticker = 'SPY'
start = datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# Download the df
df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)

# Drop the Adj Close and Volume for now
df = df.drop(['Adj Close'], axis=1)
print(df)





# Check if day of week is Monday
print('Checking for beginnings of weeks...')
df = df.reset_index() # Make the date index an actual column again for now
df['week_day_objects'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d') # make the dates a datetime object
for i in range(len(df)-1, 0, -1): # start at the bottom of the DF and work backwards
    if df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i] > df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i-1] + timedelta(days=2): # first day of week is always > 2 days since the previous date, holidays included
        continue # if today is the start of the week, continue the loop...
    else:
        df = df.drop([df.index[i]]) # ...else, drop all rows that aren't at the beginning of the week

df = df.set_index(['Date']) # make the date column the index again
df = df.drop(['week_day_objects'], axis=1) # drop the datetime column now

# For review
df.to_csv('./Check_Week_Days.csv', index=True)
```

...however, I'm stuck trying to also incorporate Friday's (or rather, the end of week) into this solution. And I'm not even sure this is the best way to do it so I'm open to suggestions. The logic above just basically looks for any day that's at least 3 days greater than the previous row, which is the beginning of the week as the beginning of a new work week always happens at least 3 days after the last work day of last week.

As requested, some clarification. Like I mentioned above, I don't just want to drop all rows that aren't Friday's or Monday's because some weeks are short weeks, so the beginning of the week could start on a Tuesday, or the end of a week could end on a Thursday, so I don't want to lose those rows. What I'd like to end up with is a dataframe of rows that start on the beginning business day of that week, and end on the last business day of that week, whether it be a Friday or Thursday/Monday or Tuesday. So the final dataset would look like this:

[image: Final_dataframe]

Notice how most weeks are Monday to Friday, however the 18th is a Tuesday because the 17th of that year was a holiday. I'm not looking to sync my calendar to holidays, I want to drop all the middle days between whatever business day started that week, and whatever business day ended that week. Hope that helps?

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you looking to merge it with a trading holidays calendar?

Comment: @rpanai No. Details are in the question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular data has to be in text format and not string. It will be great if you can show us which one is the expected output.

Comment: @rpanai See my edits above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out with the below function using the day of week numbers:

```
# Check if day of week is Monday
print('Checking for beginnings of weeks...')
df = df.reset_index() # Make the date index an actual column again for now
df['week_day_objects'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.dayofweek # make the dates a datetime object number
for i in range(len(df)-2, 1, -1): # start at the bottom of the DF and work backwards. Need to trim the top/bottom rows accordingly later.
    if (df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i] < df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i-1] and df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i] < df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i+1]) or # A beginning of the week will always have a day of week number less than the day after it, and the day before it
    (df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i] > df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i-1] and df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i] > df['week_day_objects'].iloc[i+1]): # ...and a EOW will always have a number greater than the day before it, and the day after it.

        continue # if today is the start or end of the week, skip...
    else:
        df = df.drop([df.index[i]]) # ...else, drop all rows that aren't at the beginning/end of the week

df = df.set_index(['Date']) # make the date column the index again
df = df.drop(['week_day_objects'], axis=1) # drop the datetime column now

# For review
df.to_csv('./Check_Week_Days.csv', index=True)
```

So a start of week will always have a lower number than the previous row/day's number, and it will also be lower than tomorrow's number. Reverse that for the end of week. This makes it work no matter what the Start or End of week is, being a Thursday end, or a Tuesday start.

This loop doesn't start at the very top/bottom of the dataframe though leaving some cleanup to do, but I will write a separate code to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime object's dayofweek attribute to select rows and delete those based on the index.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates_df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(np.datetime64('2000-01-03'), np.datetime64('2000-01-25')), columns=['date'])
dates_df.drop(dates_df[dates_df['date'].dt.dayofweek == 6].index)
```

The snippet above will drop all Sunday values.

But you can also select the data that matches the first or last day of the week instead of dropping it

```
dates_df[(dates_df['date'].dt.dayofweek == 1) | (dates_df['date'].dt.dayofweek == 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but like I mentioned, I'm not looking for Monday's/Friday's only, because some weeks don't have Friday's or Monday's in them due to holidays and the markets being closed for that day. So some weeks start on a Tuesday, some even start on a Wednesday (i.e. Christmas). So I can't just drop all rows that aren't Monday's or Friday's. Does this make sense? Details are in the question. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @MattWilson people it's trying to helping and you just say that details are in questions. Would you consider that eventually your question is not that clear?

Comment: @rpanai The question has been updated above to provide you with more clarification and a reproducible code. Thanks.